# Use of Model object as a param in the request handling methods

Tags: spring-mvc, model

I just want to know

Why do we use Model object as a Parameter to the request handling method in the Spring MVC application?

Basic Explanation helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelAndView` (or `Model`) is a specialized spring object to store name value pairs (kind of java `Map`). It is optional to have the Model Object as a parameter to the request method. However in case if your request method has anything that needs to be passed on to the `View`; then you need a Model.

So Model is basically a data structure that carries information from the service layer to the view layer.

You can also initialize a Model inside your request method as:

```
public ModelAndView listCarrier() {
    HashMap<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("isView", request.getParameter("isView"));
    return model;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add attribute to Model object and use that attribute inside your JSP like below.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "xyz";
    }
```

and later on you can access this property in your xyz.jsp like below.

```
Name: ${name}
```

For more info refer :-[Model API docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/ui/class-use/Model.html#org.springframework.ui)